# Error: Type is redeclared in this package

Tags: go

[image: I have this folder structure:]

In req.go, I have:

```
package basic

type Headers struct {
}

type Body struct {
}
```

and in res.go, I have the same:

```
package basic

type Headers struct {
}

type Body struct {
}
```

and so I get this error:

> 'Headers' redeclared in this package
>
> 'Body' redeclared in this package

Is the only way to solve this is to put req and res in their own folders? Ughh so many folders.

Comment: Why do you declare the same structs twice?

Comment: If those are supposed to be different structs, you need to either give them different names or put those files in separate packages. If they're supposed to be the same, you only need to define them once in the package.

Comment: The easiest way is to change package name without changing folders!

Comment: I can't change the package name, as both req.go and res.go are in the same folder, the package name has to match the folder right?

Comment: I guess the solution for golang would be for files to create namespaces, not just folders..unfortunately only folders create a namespace, not files.

Comment: @tkausl Headers in req.go pertains to a request, Headers in res.go pertains to a response. They are supposed to be different structs.

Comment: You can have multiple namespaces in a single folder

Comment: @Ehsan.Saradar how do you create multiple namespaces in a folder? Only way I know of doing that is using subfolders...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packages are the basic unit of creating separated and reusable code. From inside the package, you refer to its [identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#identifier) (identifiers declared in the package) by their name. From the "outside" (from other packages), you import the package and you refer to its identifiers using a [qualified identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers), which is

```
QualifiedIdent = PackageName "." identifier .
```

When a package consists of multiple files, each identifier declared in any of the package's files will belong to the package block. Quoting from [Spec: Declarations and scope:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)

> The scope of an identifier denoting a constant, type, variable, or function (but not method) declared at top level (outside any function) is the package block.

What this means is that you can't have the same identifier declared in 2 files of the same package.

If you think about it, this is how it should be. What happens if someone from the outside writes `basic.Header`? Which `Header` should that mean?

One option is to put them into 2 separate packages: `req` and `resp`, then you can refer to them as `req.Header` and `resp.Header`, and you know exactly what they mean just by looking at these qualified identifiers.

If you don't want 2 packages, simply rename them. Give them meaningful names, such as `ReqHeader` and `RespHeader`, and then you may refer to them like `basic.ReqHeader` and `basic.RespHeader`.

Comment: related problem if you have a moment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355954/import-subpackages-with-golang-by-importing-parent-dir