# import subpackages with golang, by importing parent dir?

Tags: go

I have this main.go file:

```
package main

import "one/entities/bar"

func main(){

}
```

I have this dir structure:

[image]

When I build my project with:

```
go install main
```

I get this compilation error:

> src/main/main.go:3:8: no Go files in
>   /home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/oredoc/test/builds/go/src/one/entities/bar

that error makes sense. Is there some way to import all the subpackages from within the `one/entities/bar` directory?

Something like this:

```
package main

import bar "one/entities/bar/*"

func main(){

}
```

(using some sort of * syntax and importing all subpackages in the bar namespace).

**Ultimately I am trying do something like this:**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "one/entities/bar"
)

func main(){

    v := bar.Get.Basic.Req.Headers{}
    log.Fatal(v)

}
```

Comment: Import statements imports a `package`. As long as the code inside the directory is of the same package, it is imported. You then can access it by `packagename.<func/var>`. Why would you subdivide single package to many? Is it necessary?

Comment: @ChenA. yeah in the bar folder, I am going to have to generate a type alias that points to each branch in the folder tree, it sux, but what I have do I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do such thing, according to the [specs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations) of `import`:

```
The import names an identifier (PackageName) to be used for access and an 
ImportPath that specifies the package to be imported.

ImportDecl       = "import" ( ImportSpec | "(" { ImportSpec ";" } ")" ) .
ImportSpec       = [ "." | PackageName ] ImportPath .
ImportPath       = string_lit .
```

The import syntax requires a package name or path of a package. So no wildcard import.

This statement will clarify the why;

```
The PackageName is used in qualified identifiers to access exported 
identifiers of the package within the importing source file.
```

You must specify in which package the element you are referring to exists. e.g, `bar.Get.Basic.Req.Headers`. This can't be determined without an explicit import.