# How to import all sub-directories from a certain app directory?

Tags: go, package, subdirectory

I am creating a http server with Golang. (I have a Php dev background.)
In the internal/app/model I plan on making several packages with artificial logic and I would wish to load all the sub-directories of the model folder in main.go.

I have following folder structure:

```
[project folder]
\_cmd
     \_main.go
.
.
.
\_internal
          \_app
               \_model
                      \_article
                      \_product
```

I have tried something in this sense without success:

```
import (
    "[project_folder]/[project]/internal/app/model/*"
)
```

Comment: That's not possible in Go. If you need all the models all the time they should probably all be in the same package. Don't make tons of tiny packages in Go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would either:

- need to place `project_folder` in `$GOPATH/src` (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33351387/6309)): the old way
- use a `go mod init project_folder` in order to declare a module named `project_folder`: the new way, with **[go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules)**. (use `set GO111MODULE=on` or `export GO111MODULE=on`)

In the latter case, your `project_folder` can be anywhere: no more `GOPATH`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The question is how to do some sort of wildcard import, importing multiple packages at once.

Comment: @Peter as in with wildcard? There is no wildcard in import, I think (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53356110/6309)